# python print a list of items

Tags: python, python-2.7

So im pretty new at python and I have a problem I can`t really get my head around. I keep getting an error from a firebase uploader script. It works fine with just 1 item however from my json file i need it to take more than one fields and everytime I try to add another field for it to read it throws me an error

> "AttributeError: 'dict' object" has no attribute 'item'.

So bellow is the part of code that when changed stops working.

```
    def main():
pool = Pool(processes=100)
data= []
try:
    data = getData(JSON_FILE)
except:
    print("please format the json file properly. Parsing error")
print(len(data))
index = 0
for item in data:
    print(str(index)+' items out of '+str(len(data))+' is done.')
    if item.item['email_client', 'persoana_contact'] != '' :
        postClientData(items)
    index+=1
pool.close()
```

And it worked fine with this bit:

```
for item in data:
    print(str(index)+' items out of '+str(len(data))+' is done.')
    if item['persoana_contact'] != '' :
        postClientData(item)
```

So what am I doing wrong, how can I make the script take more than 1 item from my json file and create the Client entity as it should?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is in `item.item['email_client', 'persoana_contact'] != ''`

```
for item in data:
...
# wrong
# if item.item['email_client', 'persoana_contact'] != '' :
      ..

# maybe you need something like this ?
if item['email_client'] != '' or item['persoana_contact'] != '':
    ...
```

Comment: ooh, i see, changing it the way you said seems to not throw any errors, however does this mean that if i need my client entity to have 8 fields from the json file i need to write them all like this: if item['value1'] != '' or item['value2'] != '' or item['value3']:, untill i have all of the fields i need?

Comment: i`m asking this because i have around 24 fields i need to read from my json file this was just a test to see if it works with more than 1

Comment: `if item['persoana_contact'] != ''` check if `persoana_contact` from your jsson is not empty, but i don't know what you what to do with your code, and what is the logic

Comment: thank you for your answer, this helped me see my problem

Comment: @DLMike you would probably want to write a loop. See [**`any`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) and [**`all`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all)